# How does Minecraft Forge load mods from external JARs?

Tags: java

How do I load a class from an external JAR that I'm not aware of prior to compiling?

The issue comes down to, "How do I get the path of a class in a jar?"

```
try {
    for (int x = 0; x < new File("mods").listFiles().length; x++) {
        if (new File("mods").listFiles()[x].getName().endsWith(".jar")) {

            JarFile file = new JarFile(new File("mods").listFiles()[x].getPath());
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = file.entries();

            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                 new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file://"+new File("mods").listFiles()[x].getAbsolutePath())}).loadClass(%path-to-class%);
                }
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: did you add the jar to classpath?

Comment: I'm trying to load from JARs that I don't know about prior.

Comment: Use a `URLClassLoader` pointing to the URL of the JAR you would like to load.

Comment: Do?: new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL(%path-to-jar%)}).loadClass(%path-to-class%);

Comment: @skilcox You should not add the solution and remove the question. You should leave the question so other users can understand what the problem is for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this.

```
try
{
    // Get all the files in mod folder
    File[] mods = new File("mod").listFiles();

    for (int i=0; i<mods.length; i++)
    {
        // Skip if the file is not a jar
        if (!mods[i].getName().endsWith(".jar"))
            continue;

        // Create a JarFile
        JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(mods[i]);

        // Get the entries
        Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();

        // Create a URL for the jar
        URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + mods[i].getAbsolutePath() +"!/") };
        cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

        while (e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();

            // Skip directories
            if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // -6 because of .class
            String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
            className = className.replace('/', '.');

            // Load the class
            Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I got the solution from this. ^.^